# github page css not showing properly

Tags: css

Here is the link of my website:
https://foysalmeazi.github.io/foysalportfolio/
when I visit the website it show only html but css is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

It missing bootstrap on your web, in html code:

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

change to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Folder on path is case sensitive.

Comment: Now it says There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Comment: I see https://foysalmeazi.github.io/foysalportfolio/ it works, or where do you see that warning?